# Consulta com between usando Strings em Java com JPQL

Tags: java, oracle, java-ee, jpql

tenho uma dúvida quanto a consulta com **JPQL** usando o **BETWEEN com Strings**,
tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
select t from Entidade t "
            + "where t.data >= :dataTal "
            + "and t.numeroProcurado between :sequenciaInicial and :sequenciaFinal "
            + "order by t.numeroProcurado DESC
```

**Qual o objetivo?** Preciso verificar se existe na base algum "numeroProcurado" existente entre a sequenciaInicial e Final que recebo e estou passando como parâmetro, porém em alguns casos isso retorna numeros que estão fora dessas sequencias informadas, não sei por que.

As sequencias tem o seguinte formato:   sequenciaInicial "LL00000001" sequenciaFinal "LL00000010" o numero procurado tem o mesmo formato, porém tenho duvidas se essa consulta que fiz e a melhor forma para obter essa resposta, peguei casos onde a sequencia inicial informada era "LL00004000" e final "LL00004020" porem retornou sequencias com numeros menores ex: "LL00000400","LL00000410".

Enfim alguem sabe uma outra melhor forma?

Lembrando que esse retorno eu vou usar para uma tomada de decisão posterior, ou seja se voltar um valor dessa consulta segue de um jeito se não voltar segue de outro...

Comment: Não faz sentido ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87935b/1

Comment: Por ex: essa consulta select * from TABELA
where CAMPO_DATA >= to_date('2020-08-22','yyyy-MM-dd')
and VALOR_REGISTRADO_NA_BASE BETWEEN 'AA000006224' and 'AA00006235'    Essa consulta trouxe valores da seguinte numeração >> AA00000660,AA00000663, AA00000876 trouxe vários valores assim até chegar num valor verdadeiro  AA000006224 e AA000006225

Comment: Tem um zero a mais na 6224 as strings não alinham , é isto mesmo ?

Comment: Isso, em alguns casos tem menos caracteres do que o padrão que e 10.

Comment: Mas a busca padrão em string está correta.

Comment: A formação é sempre esta ao menos AA + número ? Tentou a busca extraindo a parte numérica ? Substr e to_number.

Comment: Sim sempre essa com AA no inicio, não tentei a busca extraindo a parte numérica, na verdade pensei nisso mas não consegui chegar em um raciono, como seria?

Comment: Tente To_number(Substr(campo,3,(length(campo)-2)))

Comment: Cara eu dei uma estudada no to_number, até consegui usar, mas nesse contexto ai dessa query com between não consegui, poderia me mandar um exemplo com meu modelo de query para eu me basear por favor?

Comment: + "and To_number(Substr(t.numeroProcurado,3,(length(campo)-2))) between To_number(Substr(:sequenciaInicial,3,(length(campo)-2))) and To_number(Substr(:sequenciaFinal,3,(length(campo)-2))) " ... tente isto

Comment: Vlw extraindo a parte numero funcionou bem, o problema e que esse banco aqui ta com os dados meio zuados, tem muitos padrões, mas por números funcionou direitinho obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme o @Motta explicou fazendo a query pela parte numero usando o to_number funcionou, o problema, na verdade, está ralacionado aos dados do banco de dados que estou usando para testes, ele está bem zuado com padrões antigos e novos das sequências que eu informou, mas pelos números funfou certinho.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Crie uma novam coluna ajustando para a busca , alimente via update e trigger , depois crie um índice se necessário.

Comment: Sim essa seria uma boa, porem a base de dados fica na mão de outra empresa, tem uma burocraciaenorme para qualquer modificação mesmo que mínima, de todo modo deu para resolver sem precisar dessa criação.